# why do the posts seem to change when i look at the recent tagged instagram API

Tags: instagram

when i'm accessing the instagram API via the https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent and i click refresh on the browser, it seems to get more posts, but the count doesn't change on the app in iOS or on the API. Is there actually more posts being posted or is it just cycling through old ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maximal limit of returned media per request: 33 (by now). By default the API should return 20 items. **Regardless of refreshing the browser, the number of posts per request does not change.**

I assume that you were getting the same number of media after refreshing the browser, but they were new, just being posted on the Instagram. However, they could have more data (longer descriptions etc.), which could give you an illusive impression of more fetched items.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. However - I mean the count when viewed by the Instagram endpoint: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter . This value does not change when comparing it to the /media/recent endpoint.

Comment: Oh, I see. "nofilter" tag is quite popular, so while you are refreshing the browser you are getting new photos from the Instagram. It does not cycle through the old ones (you should use pagination for that purpose). Test it with some less popular tag name (eg. "słupsk", my hometown) and you will see the returned data does not change so quickly.